# About gluing of sheaves on a cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Suppose we are given a cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of a space $X$ and a gluing data $ ( \mathcal{F}_i, \psi_{ij} )_{i,j \in I}$ for the sheaves of sets with respect to this covering.  I want to show that there is a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on X whose restriction to each $U_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F_i}$. I have proved it in a direct way i.e. by defining a suitable sheaf that takes open sets of $X$ to compatible tuples and showing that it satisfies all the required properties. Now, there is a hint given in the book I'm following, that is to construct this sheaf by extending a sheaf on a base. And the mentioned base is the collection of open sets which are contained in some $U_i$.

So, if I define right away the sheaf on a base to be $\mathcal{F}^*(u):= \mathcal{F}_i (u)$, where $u\subset U_i$ for some $i\in I$ and the restriction map to be the restriction map of corresponding $U_i$, then the gluability and identity axiom on the base become immediate. However, I'm not sure if this $\mathcal{F}^*$ is well defined, as given $w\subset U_i \cap U_j$, we have $\mathcal{F}_i(w) \cong \mathcal{F}_j(w)$ but not equal. How should i improvise this definition?

Comment: To me, all of your work is correct. Are you worried about isomorphism vs equality? Because the same idea comes up in your first construction.

Comment: @SamCanning Yes, that is my issue. And I kind off missed that in the first proof.

Comment: You use the isomorphisms $\psi_{ij}$ when saying your tuples are compatible. I don't have much to say about the difference between isomorphism and equality besides "don't worry about it," but maybe someone more inclined toward foundations could answer your question. Basically, the reason I say "don't worry about it" is that any construction you'll do with sheaves later won't care about equality versus isomorphism because, loosely speaking, "things are functorial."